# Scraping Javascript based websites with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data from here (using python 2.7):

http://financials.morningstar.com/valuation/earnings-estimates.html?t=AMD

When I right click and choose "View Page Sources" in Chrome browser, the content that I am looking for is not there. For example I am looking for "Average Rating".

I searched Stackoverflow and saw this question and answer:
[Python 3, Web-scraping, and Javascript [Oh My]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804497/python-3-web-scraping-and-javascript-oh-my)
But when I tried the main answer, I could not find any `XMLHttpRequest` function.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: In the Firefox network inspector I see 3 AJAX requests (click "XHR" at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker. Sure I used the Firefox and now I see a number of "Get" and "Post". How can I use this information now?

Comment: Similar for the network inspector in Chrome. Click on network, click the XHR filter, open the M* page, you'll see 3 XHR items, click on one of them in the left column (name), you'll then see a URL - copy that and go to the page in your browserl

Comment: Thanks foosion. Strangely I cannot see this in Chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data you want is pulled from

```
http://financials.morningstar.com/valuation/annual-estimate-list.action?&t=XNAS:AMD&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&r=1425167484279.9668&_=1425167484280
http://financials.morningstar.com/valuation/analyst-opinion-list.action?&t=XNAS:AMD&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&r=1425167484282.3906&_=1425167484282
http://financials.morningstar.com/valuation/forward-comparisons-list.action?&t=XNAS:AMD&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&r=1425167484284.5396&_=1425167484284
```

You should be able to scrape these urls directly.

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. Did you use Chrome to find these?

Comment: No, I used Firefox with the HttpFox toolbar (from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/)

Comment: Thanks again. I installed httpfox, when I run it I see a lot of URLs, how do you know which one to pick?

Comment: In HttpFox, look at the Type column. You can ignore `text/css` (formatting), `text/javascript` (javascript - _could_ include dynamic data but usually not), and `image/gif` (pictures). This leaves the main page (we have already established it does not hold the data you want), a favicon file with the wrong data type (should be `image/x-icon`), the three files listed above, and an `application/json` file (data for the commodity quotes ticker at the top of the page).